# Build VLC for iOS got error(iOS SDK 6.1, MAC OSX 10.8.3)

Tags: ios, vlc

I tried to build VLC for iOS, below are my steps:

```
mkdir vlc
cd vlc
git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/ios.git
cd vlc/ios
./buildMobileVLC.sh -k iphoneos6.1
```

and finally get error, that is:

```
...
[info] Removing unneeded modules
~/Documents/VLC/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/package/ios
[info] Building MobileVLCKit (Aggregate static plugins, Release)
[info] Building MobileVLCKit (MobileVLCKit, Release)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Release-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMobileVLCKit.a normal armv7
Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Release-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libMobileVLCKit.a normal armv7s
(2 failures)
```

and then I clean and rebuild it, there are no explicit error message, the last section of build message is:

```
/Users/Awin/Documents/VLC/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/lib/media_player.c:1274:25: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum input_query_e' to different enumeration type 'vlc_action_t' (aka 'enum vlc_action')
  [-Wenum-conversion]
    INPUT_NAV_LEFT, INPUT_NAV_RIGHT,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
7 warnings generated.
[info] Installing libvlc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Awin/Documents/VLC/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/vlc/libcompat.a(dummy.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Awin/Documents/VLC/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/vlc/libcompat.a(tdestroy.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Awin/Documents/VLC/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/libvlccore.a(cache.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Awin/Documents/VLC/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/libvlccore.a(update_crypto.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Awin/Documents/VLC/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/vlc/plugins/control/libmotion_plugin.a(libmotion_plugin_la-unimotion.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Awin/Documents/VLC/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/armv7/lib/vlc/plugins/video_filter/librotate_plugin.a(librotate_plugin_la-unimotion.o) has no symbols
[info] Removing unneeded modules
~/Documents/VLC/ios/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/package/ios
[info] Building MobileVLCKit (Aggregate static plugins, Release)
[info] Building MobileVLCKit (MobileVLCKit, Release)
** BUILD FAILED **"
```

How do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: it does not show the cause of error.